# what are the criteria for deleting vs closing a question?

Tags: discussion

For example, [this question about a GMRS hand held that is answered in the manual](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/22090/removing-dcs-codes-from-retevis-rb27) is both poorly researched (not researched at all... it's in the dang manual that I don't have but is the first google result when searching for model manual) AND it's not relevant to the community, even tangentially.

In short, it is not fixable. It's of negative value to anyone looking for amateur radio related stuff.

Why is it not ok to delete it (I flagged it for deletion but was marked unhelpful) but it is ok to close it?

Did I simply wake up on the wrong side of the bed (a *distinct* possiblilty, frequently bordering on probable)?

Comment: If you make a small change to it, then I could remove my upvote. :)

Comment: made a change to the answer!

Comment: I've been thinking that you might make a good moderator. :-)

Comment: thanks for the vote of confidence Mike! However, my ability to participate on the site is very erratic. Also, I recognize that my ability to remember to respond with kindness and generosity—something all posters deserve—is far from perfect. for these reasons and others, I think it best to spare our community from me ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I handled that flag, and perhaps I could have done better. Let me tell you what I was thinking.

At the time, my impression of the argument presented was that the question was “low effort”, and on general principles of how Stack Exchange works — two people judging “low effort” is not *by itself* a justification for total deletion; it's a justification for downvotes. I'd have been more likely to go ahead and delete it if the question had had multiple downvotes at the time.

(So, to answer the titular question — I see the criteria for deletion as that *there is some consensus* that it is bad and not fixable, or that it's *blatantly* bad in some way, like being spam.)

However, I did not notice that the radio being asked about was a GMRS, not amateur, model, and therefore off-topic, interpreted strictly. (I'm a little skeptical that it's *useful* to draw the line “this is a voice, simplex, analog transceiver used by hobbyists *but not hams,* so it is irrelevant to this site”. But that's a different discussion entirely.) If I had noticed this factor, I might have at least closed the question.

---

By the way, now that the question *is* closed,

- [You have the ability](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to cast a deletion *vote.*
- It would eventually meet [the criteria for automatic deletion](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions), except that it has an upvoted answer (yours).

In the future, please consider *not answering* questions you consider low quality; the presence and vote score of answers is one of the signs the system takes into account when judging the question they're attached to. (It is also something of a “conflict of interest” situation, at least for *closing* questions; if someone answers a question and also causes it to be closed, then nobody else can answer, which makes it easier for the sole answer to gather reputation for that person and no one else.)

---

P.S. I'm not saying “the situation is fine and I recommend against any further action”. I'm only, for the moment, answering the question you asked and trying to provide as much context as I can think of.

Comment: I'm the one that upvoted it. I'll try and keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I answered it is because it was suggested to move my comment to an answer. I didn't know that upvoted answers are a signal to the system... thanks for sharing the rationale and the info!!

Comment: @webmarc and at that time I didn't know the OQ was OT.

Comment: yeah, I feel this one was a learning experience all around for all of us!

Comment: Kevin, I'm not sure it came across in my previous comments: I sincerely appreciate the time you took to share the thinking behind the action, and in your shoes would have most certainly made the same conclusions and decisions myself. Thanks for moderating!